# angular pass component to component as parameter

Tags: angular, angular-components

I try to build a reusable list which displays elements of type T.
The view of these elements depends on T.
To break this dependency I decided to also pass the view component.

> E.g. The list contains elements of type "Car". The view passing to this list is used to display the attributes ".ps" and ".color" of each element.

Sadly, I am a Newbie in Angular and I can't figure how to do this right.
I would like to do something like this:

generic-list.ts

```
export class GenericListComponent<T> { 
    @Input() readonly elements: T[]; // Array of objects to be listed; 
    @Input() embeddedComponentAsViewForEachGivenElementOfTypeT: any;
... 
}
```

generic-list.html

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let el of elements">
        <embeddedComponentAsViewForEachGivenElementOfTypeT [element]=el </embeddedComponentAsViewForEachGivenElementOfTypeT>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Using the list could look like this :

```
  <app-generic-list [elements]="ArrayOfComplexObjects"
                         [embeddedComponentAsViewForEachGivenElementOfTypeT]="ViewComponentToDisplayComplexObject"> </app-generic-list>
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks :)

---- Update:

I take Brandons answer but changed the implementation a little bit by using *ngSwitchCase and adding a factory component.
The bad thing about this approach is that everytime a new ListElement comes in, the factory component has to be modfied (violation of "Open-Close-Principle". On the other hand is this dependency kept in one factory.

Here is the Code:

generic-list-html

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let el of elements">
        <app-factory-listelement elementToDisplay="el" typeOfListElement="carListElement"> </app-factory-listelement>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

factory-listelement.ts

```
export class FactoryListelementComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() typeOfListElement: string;
    @Input() elementToDisplay: any;
    carType = 'carListElement';
    bikeType = 'bikeListElement';
    ...
```

factory-listelement.html

```
<div [ngSwitch]="typeOfListElement">
    <app-car-info-list-element TheCarElement="elementToDisplay" *ngSwitchCase="carType" >...</app-car-info-list-element>
    <app-bike-info-list-element TheBikeElement="elementToDisplay" *ngSwitchCase="bikeType" >...</app-bike-info-list-element>
    <!--default case when there are no matches -->
    <div *ngSwitchDefault> ERROR ! Make some error.log or so</div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible. The HTML element used to reference the "embeddedComponent..." is not data binded like element attributes can be. What you could do is have a restricted number of child components within the list and pass a parameter like `type` in, which would instruct the component to use one of the available child components.

So then in generic-list.html you'd have something like:

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let el of elements">

    <component-option-one
      *ngIf="type === 'componentOptionOne'"
    ></component-option-one>

    <component-option-two
      *ngIf="type === 'componentOptionTwo'"
    ></component-option-two>

    <component-option-three
      *ngIf="type === 'componentOptionThree'"
    ></component-option-three>

  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

And you'd create it with:

```
<app-generic-list
  [elements]="arrayOfElements"
  [type]="'componentOptionOne'"
></app-generic-list>
```